# SQL Server 2012/2008R2 on Different Servers not seeing each other

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, replication

Hi I have a desktop server running Windows 7 and S.S. 2008 R2. It's been running a long time with stability. I recently purchased a laptop running Windows 8.1 and S.S. 2012/BI. Historically I have done all of my development (Python/S.S. SPROCs, etc) on the Windows 7 desktop. Eventually S.S. 2008 R2 will be ugpraded to S.S. 2012. Right now, I want the freedom to continue my development on either and not worry about manually copying back/forth.  Ultimately I want to set up some form of replication. However I have more immediate problems.

To start, I would like to just get a copy of the database from the S.S. 2008 R2 instance copied to the S.S. 2012/BI instance. I cannot seem to get the file sharing between the two computers/instances correct to allow one instance to access the other. Here is what I have attempted and the obstacles in front of me, to just get a copy of the S.S. 2008 R2 DB copied to the 2012/BI instance.

(FYI there is a successful 'home group' setup between the 2 windows instances. For example, I can see the pictures on the Win7 box from the Win8 laptop. I have also set up a share/network drive on the Win7 box pointing to my S.S. 2008 R2 DB Backup)

1 - I went into S.S. 2012 SS Mgmt Studio, highlighted 'Database', right clicked, selected 'Restore Database', walked through the dialog box under source, selected 'device' then hit the button with 3 dots, it brings up 'select backup devices', hit 'add' looking for the mapped network drive pointing to the Win7 box with the 2008 R2 backup. PROBLEM: The network drive will not show up.

2 - On the Win 7 box I tried the 'copy database wizard' - 2008 R2 can see the laptop but after that and by hitting the 'next' button, it eventually times out with 'Failed to connect to server ' and 'Login failed for user 'Laptop\Guest' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456) BTW this was AFTER I temporarily shut down the firewall on the laptop/copy destination.

Again, my first objective is just a manual copy from 2008R2 to 2012BI. If someone can coach me on connectivity/permissions/etc I would appreciate.

After I get a copy set up, I would appreciate some guidance on the appropriate replication scheme to employ and how to set it up. I would like to be able work on the 2008R2 instance and at anytime be able to grab my laptop (SS 2012/BI) and be assured it has all of the most recent 2008R2 changes. Then after I finish my work on the laptop (2012/BI) have the laptop changes replicate back to the desktop (2008/R2...but this will eventually also be 2012/BI)

Thanks in abvance

Answer (score 0):

I can;t comment so will put my few cents here ;)
Did you made your sql server database backup on Windows 7 on network drives / natwrok share which is available in Windows explorer in you new Windows 8 laptop ?